# Bootstrap 5 Carousel Not Working with Responsive Resizing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get my carousel to work however after I changed the size of it all it breaks the carousel itself and I am not exactly sure. Any help would be great as I am very new to responsive designs. I'm not really sure how this all works but my placeholder images do scale to the size of the device well. So I am just not sure why the carousel is no longer working.

Thanks in advance all!

```css
      /*Main*/

      html, body
      {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
          overflow-x: hidden; 
          background-color: lightgreen;
      }

    /*NavBar*/

      #logo-space{
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #0f2471;
      }

      #logo-space img{
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        left: 2rem;
      }

      .nav-bar{
          background-color: #16377e;
          position: relative;
      }
    
      #navbar-space .nav-link{
        position: relative;
        left: 4rem;
      }


    /*Carousel*/

    .home .carousel-item{
      min-height: 100vh;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .home .carousel-item:before{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .home .carousel-item.active h2{
      animation: fadeInLeft 0.5s ease forwards;
    }

    .home .carousel-item.active p{
      animation: fadeInRight 0.5s ease forwards;
    }

    /*responsive*/
    @media(max-width: 767px){
      .home .carousel-control-next, 
      .home .carousel-control-prev{
        display: none;
      }
      .home .carousel-indicators li{
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
      }
      .home .carousel-item h2{
        font-size: 45px;
      }
      .home .carousel-item p{
        font-size: 22px;
      }
      
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b5212ab333.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!--Index Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    <style type="text/css">
      
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <!--Logo Space-->
      <div id="logo-space">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <img src="img/logo.png" class="image-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    <!--Nav Bar-->
    <div id="home">
      <nav id="navbar-space" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg nav-bar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="#home">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white " href="#divisions">DIVISIONS</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white " href="#appeals">APPEALS</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!--Carousel-->
      
    <section id="carouselSection" class="home carousel slide position-absolute" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x700" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x700" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x700" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you including the Javascript CDN in your project? In your snippet, it's missing. You need that in order for the carousel to do anything. https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Ye that seems to have fixed it but for some reason, now my nav bar is not working. The drop down I mean while in mobile mode.

Comment: Fixed, forgot to add JS

Comment: Ye its worked however the about-us is not above the hero-img, its looking like this: 
https://gyazo.com/893beb4d71b31ac3676dfa81629af46c

Comment: Would z-index fix this or?